# CruiseControl multiple source folders

Tags: configuration, cruisecontrol.net

I want to compile a project (with CruiseControl) not only if its source changes, but also if some dependencies change.

example:
I got 3 folders:

c:\myProject\src      (my source folder)
c:\dependency1\src    (source code of dependency 1)
c:\dependency2\output (dll of dependency 2)

I want to compile my project in cruisecontrol if anything in one of these folders change.

How can I configure this in my ccnet.config?

bye and thanks
juergen

Comment: I forgot to mention that myProject is in SVN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the dependencies setup as subversion externals, then follow the instructions on [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374818/how-to-configure-svn-task-in-cruisecontrol-net-to-detect-subversion-external-chan).

If they are each in their own subversion repository, you might try something like [this post by Mark Cohen](http://beingmarkcohen.com/?p=119).

If the changes are only at the filesystem level, then you might try the [`<filesystem>`](http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Filesystem%20Source%20Control%20Block.html) modification set detector.

Answer (score 4):

Should be something like this:

```
<project>
  <!-- ... -->
  <sourcecontrol type="multi">
    <requireChangesFromAll>False</requireChangesFromAll>
    <sourceControls>
      <svn>
        <trunkUrl>svn://svn.mycompany.com/myProject/trunk</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>c:\myProject\src</workingDirectory>
        <!-- ... -->
      </svn>
      <svn>
        <trunkUrl>svn://svn.mycompany.com/dependency1/trunk</trunkUrl>
        <workingDirectory>c:\dependency1\src</workingDirectory>
        <!-- ... -->
      </svn>
      <filtered>
        <exclusionFilters />
        <inclusionFilters>
          <pathFilter>
            <caseSensitive>False</caseSensitive>
            <pattern>c:\dependency2\output\dependency2.dll</pattern>
          </pathFilter>
        </inclusionFilters>
        <sourceControlProvider type="filesystem">
          <autoGetSource>False</autoGetSource>
          <ignoreMissingRoot>True</ignoreMissingRoot>
          <repositoryRoot>c:\dependency2\output</repositoryRoot>
        </sourceControlProvider>
      </filtered>
    </sourceControls>
  </sourcecontrol>
  <!-- ... -->
</project>
```